# Unable to get the desired portion kicking out the rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to grab address from a webpage. When I execute my script I get the address like `Zimmerbachstr. 51, 74676 Niedernhall-Waldzimmern Germany`. They all are within this selector `"[itemprop='address']"`. However, my question is how can i get the address except for the country name which  is within `"[itemprop='addressCountry']"`.

The total address are within this block of html:

```
<div class="push-half--bottom " itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">Zimmerbachstr. 51</span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode">74676</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Niedernhall-Waldzimmern</span><br>
    <span itemprop="addressCountry">Germany</span><br>
</div>
```

If I try like below I can get the desired portion of address but this is not an ideal way at all:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<div class="push-half--bottom " itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">Zimmerbachstr. 51</span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode">74676</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Niedernhall-Waldzimmern</span><br>
    <span itemprop="addressCountry">Germany</span><br>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
[country.extract() for country in soup.select("[itemprop='addressCountry']")]
item = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("[itemprop='address']")]
print(item)
```

This is the expected output `Zimmerbachstr. 51, 74676 Niedernhall-Waldzimmern`.

***To be clearer: I would like to have any oneliner solution without any hardcoded index applied (because the country name may not always appear in the last position).***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [`lxml.html`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
from lxml import html

content = """
<div class="push-half--bottom " itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">Zimmerbachstr. 51</span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode">74676</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Niedernhall-Waldzimmern</span><br>
    <span itemprop="addressCountry">Germany</span><br>
</div>
"""

source = html.fromstring(content)
address = ", ".join([span.text for span in source.xpath("//div[@itemprop='address']/span[@itemprop='streetAddress' or @itemprop='postalCode' or @itemprop='addressLocality']")])
```

or

```
address = ", ".join([span.text for span in source.xpath("//div[@itemprop='address']/span[not(@itemprop='addressCountry')]")])
```

Output:

```
'Zimmerbachstr. 51, 74676, Niedernhall-Waldzimmern'
```

Comment: Unfortunately `BeautifulSoup` doesn't support pseudoselectors otherwise I could have managed that using the way you have shown in your provided xpath. However, If any solution related to `BeautifulSoup` comes in your mind, please drop that here as well. Thanks sir, for everything.

Comment: in bs4 something like `", ".join([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("div > span") if item.attrs['itemprop'] != 'addressCountry'])` should work as well